# A difficulty in know convergence at 1,-1 .

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to know if the series $∑_{n=1}^∞(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+⋯+\frac{1}{n})\, x^n$ converge or diverges for $x = 1$ and $x = -1$?

I am  confused about the general term $a_{n} = (1+\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+⋯+\frac{1}{n})\ $ and how to find the limit of it, I know that if its limit not equal to zero at both points then the series diverges at both points by divergence test, but I do not know how to find its limit, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: This is the most well-known divergent series; it is $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\dots+\frac{1}{n})=\infty}$. You can find this proof literally almost everywhere

Comment: The coefficient diverges, for $x=1$, this is a series of positive terms, each one is unbounded, so it diverges. For -1, what are the partial sums?

Comment: @enedil I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a series $\sum a_n$ to converge it is necessary that $a_n \to 0$. Let us prove by contradiction that the given series does not converge for $x =\pm 1$. Suppose it converges. Then $(1+\frac 1 2+\cdots+\frac 1 n) x^{n} \to 0$. This implies (taking $\epsilon =1$ in  the definition of limit) that $|1+\frac 1 2+\cdots+\frac 1 n|<1$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. [I have used the fact that $|x^{n}|=|x|^{n}=1$ when $x =\pm 1$]. But it is a well known result that $1+\frac 1 2+\cdots+\frac 1 n  \to \infty$ as $ n \to \infty$. We have arrived at a contradiction. Hence the series is divergent.

Comment: Is there a proof on this site for this well known result?

Comment: @hopefully There are many posts about it on this site. You an either search for 'divergence of harmonic series' or look at the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115613/question-on-the-proof-of-divergence-of-harmonic-series

Comment: Is this considered as a harmonic series? I thought that it is different.

Comment: It is the harmonic series. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: Could you clarify how is this a harmonic series please?(I already know the formula for harmonic series)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, if $x=1\lor x=-1$, then $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(x^n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)\ge \limsup_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac1k\ge 1$$

Comment: I do not understand anything